# Orthonormal vector question

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

It's about question (a), I know how to use the gram schmidt process, however I am missing the third vector in $A$. As it has to be linearly independent can I just choose a random random vector and make sure it is not dependent? Or is there some special way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a pair of orthonormal vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ then you can complete to an orthonormal basis by taking their cross product.

Comment: Haha! I knew it was something simple, thank you, been scratching my head for a while now!

Comment: @KarlMorrison - No problem!

Comment: Oh! One more question, would this also apply for a pair of orthogonal vectors, would that result in a third orthogonal vector?

Comment: If two vectors $v$ and $w$ are linearly independent, then $v \times w$ is orthogonal to both $v$ and $w$. So in particular, the answer to your question is yes.